# How to add checkout state conditionally in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Spree has the following code in order.rb

```
checkout_flow do
  go_to_state :address
  go_to_state :delivery
  go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) { order.payment_required? }
  go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
  go_to_state :complete
  remove_transition from: :delivery, to: :confirm
end
```

I want to add `delivery` state to order only if some condition is true.

Something like

```
insert_checkout_step :delivery, after: :address, if: :some_condition
```

I didn't find any such thing in [**spree docs**](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/checkout.html#modifying-the-checkout-flow)

Comment: you try redefining the entire checkout flow with `checkout_flow do ... end`??

Comment: It's not about skipping a step I want to add it conditionally so even if I redefine the flow I need a way to add it conditionally

Comment: but you can use `if` like the original flow `go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }`